# ffmpeg: How to use milliseconds in FFmpeg's drawblock?

Tags: ffmpeg

I am trying to generate the movement of a point on the video, this requires a sensitivity equal to the millisecond, but when I execute the command the point manages to move on the video with a sensitivity of the second, is it possible to increase the sensitivity during the creation of the video?
My command is:

```
ffmpeg -y -i video.mp4 -vf "drawbox=enable='between(t,5.1,5.4)':x=10:y=10:w=10:h=10:color=red@0.5:t=fill,drawbox=enable='between(t\,5.5,5.7)':x=10:y=10:w=10:h=10:color=red@0.5:t=fill ... " out.mp4
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you want to achieve but you can try 5.001 for example, that's 5s + 1ms. But I think it's better to use frames in this case, instead of seconds, using `between(n,10,15)` for example

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I have been able to solve it :) Stupidly I used a basic video with a framerate of 1. I have set the framerate to 25 and now it works very well. There is no need to use frames, but simply the `between` with the variable `t`